# how to compare items in an array?

Tags: arrays, sorting, p5.js

I want to do this more as an exercise in the understanding of the for statements. with that in mind, I am not looking for the most efficient way of coding, nor am I looking for obscure functions. (think of it as See Dick Run level as opposed to Shakespeare).

This is for a Secret Santa Generator.
I built one in VBA for excel. and it cycled through cells and use the BASIC line number method to escape the for loops. `( if cells(x,1)=Cells(x,2) then Goto 20)`.  I want to step up the game with this P5JS version.

I want to have an array of names.
From that array I want to shuffle the names and build a new array.
Conditions:

1. Names can not repeat.
2. The new array will be paired up with the old array so the same index of the old array cannot have the same value as the index of the new array
3. There will be forbidden pairs.

I am able to succesfully run through item but most of the time there is a recursion issue.

The possible problem is that I don't think it picks a new random each time through, it simply seems to cycle through the code picking the same values each time through.

`originalArray[a,b,c,d,e]` 
Desired `selectArray[b,a,e,c,d]`
unwanted `selectArray[c,b,e,a,d]` because `selectArray[1] == originalArray[1]`.

If I get the desired outcome, all is right with the world,
But if I get the unwanted outcome, then I get the "Too Much Recursion" error and the console.logs display the same letters over and over and over again.

```
let originalArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
let unwantedArray = [["A", "B"],["B", "A"]];
let workingArray = [];
let name;
let selectArray = [];

function setup() {
 Initialize();
}


function Initialize() {
  // this gets called when there was a conflict, reverts the working array to the original
  arrayCopy(originalArray, workingArray);
  randomArray();
}

function randomArray() {
  // picks  a random index from workingArray and assigns it to selectArray
  //Loop until workingArray is empty
  for (var x = 0; x < originalArray.length; x++) {
    name = random(workingArray);
    append(selectArray, name);
    // now remove the picked index from the workingArray
    for (var i = 0; i < workingArray.length; i++) {
      if (workingArray[i] == name) {
        workingArray.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log("random function workingArray"+ workingArray);
  console.log("random function selectArray"+ selectArray);
  Verify();
}

function Verify() {
  // compare the originalArray to the selectArray
  for (i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
    if (originalArray[i] == selectArray[i]) {
    console.log(        "original: " + originalArray[i] + "     select: " + selectArray[i]      );
      //Initialize();
    }
  }
  CheckPairs();
}

function CheckPairs() {
  console.log(" Original: " + originalArray + "    Mixed:  " + selectArray);
}
```

You will note that I call the function Initialize if there is an wanted match. I have commented it out to avoid the recursion, Also the check pairs function is yet to be built, but in a nut shell it will work as this:( I am not looking for the answer and if I get stuck will open a second question. Just throwing it out there for completeness)
if `originalArray[] == unwantedArray[0[0]]` (not sure how to notate the first position of the 2d array) then  if `selectArray[0]= unwantedArray[0[0,0]]` ( again unsure of proper notation).  I figure a for loop to check and plan was to send to Initialize() if there is a match to try this again.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the initialize function wasn't clearing out the the selectArray. Basically it just kept appending to the original array.
I changed the function to be the following and it seems to work

```
function Initialize() {
  // this gets called when there was a conflict, reverts the working array to the original
  arrayCopy(originalArray, workingArray);
  selectArray=[];
  randomArray();
}
```